# Prophecy of the Popes: appropriate question?

Tags: support

I read [this](http://io9.com/5984209/popes-resignation-brings-doomsday-prophecy) article about the "Prophecy of the Popes" recently, and then browsed the [corresponding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prophecy_of_the_Popes) Wikipedia article. Neither provided a particularly balanced view or much of a real, skeptical alternative viewpoint. Is this an appropriate for this site?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does have notoriety.  Of course, it will probably be moot by the end of March...